# Is there any way to install or covert jekyll themes into hexo?

Tags: hexo

I like to use hexo as my static site generator; however, many of the themes that I like are available in jekyll only.

Is there any way to install or convert jekyll themes into hexo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to convert jekyll themes to hexo directly since they are two completely different tools , they even use different languages jekyll is built using ruby so it's plugins are built for ruby to while hexo is built using javascript.

But since themes at the end of the day are just a bunch of html, css and js files that are edited to get the markdown in them while generation you can rip that from an existing jekyll theme and try creating a hexo theme using the same html css and js .

Comment: Thank you for help. Then I am staying with jekyll since it has the most set of themes and cummunity sypport available.

Comment: To me they are two different tools , if you are building a blog specially your own personal blog and do not want to mess alot with plugins like discus to add comments to your blog or google analytics most hexo themes get with these stuff because hexo is made for just blogs while jekyll is a more general static site generator